# How to refresh parent page when action is done in ModalBottomSheet Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am trying to make an eCommerce app using Flutter. When I click on the product it will show a bottom sheet with detailed information of the product. The idea is that once I add the product to the shopping cart, a number will appear on the top of the shopping cart icon detailing the amount of products you have saved on the shopping cart.

[Shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7NO6.png)

Once I click on the save to shopping cart bottom, the bottom sheet will close, however, the parent page does not refresh and it still shows the previous saved amount

```
void openBotomSheet(Product product){
  showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => ClientProductsDetailPage(product: product),
);
```

I tried using this solution found on the internet, with no luck

```
Widget _cardProduct(Product product){ 
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: ()async{
     await _con.openBotomSheet(product);
     setState((){});
    },
  child: Container( 'Content Here' )
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your function from this:

```
void openBotomSheet(Product product){
  showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => ClientProductsDetailPage(product: product),
);
```

To

```
Future openBotomSheet(Product product) async {
  return await showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => ClientProductsDetailPage(product: product),
);
```

And your GestureDetector to this:

```
Widget _cardProduct(Product product){ 
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: ()async{
     _con.openBotomSheet(product).then((value){
      // Do refresh function here
      // Also take setState inside, to rebuild the widget
     setState((){});
     });;
    },
  child: Container( 'Content Here' )
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't think there is something like `showMaterialModalBottomSheet` therefore I have used the closest similar widget which is `showModalBottomSheet`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, after doing the changes you mentioned, it is still not having the desired result. Only after I go to another page and enter the product page again, the number on the shopping cart updates

Comment: I understand your query, it is rather an issue of state management. I suggest you should check Provider (which is the most basic solution) to solve your problem, as I do not have an understanding of how your application is designed/works. This is the only optimum solution I could see.